# Is it possible to bind a PDO parameter to the member variable of an object?

Tags: php, oop, prepared-statement, pdo

Using [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), one can bind a parameter to a variable—which is especially useful when a prepared statement is executed multiple times, each with different parameter values.  For example:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=foo', 'eggyal', 'password1');
$qry = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM bar WHERE qux = ?');
$qry->bindParam(1, $qux, PDO::PARAM_INT);

while (true) {
  $qux = ... ;
  $qry->execute();
  // etc
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to bind a parameter to the member variable of an object?  For example:

   ```
   $qry->bindParam(1, $obj->qux, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   ```
2. If so, *to which object*'s member variable is such a parameter bound: that which is referenced at the time of the `bindParam()` call, or that which is referenced upon statement execution?  For example:

   ```
   $obj->qux = 123;

   $obj = new stdClass();
   $obj->qux = 456;

   $qry->execute();  // which value is used for qux ?
   ```
3. Where is this behaviour documented (if at all)?

Comment: It's bound to an instance property of the object at binding time. Creating a new object and assigning it to the previous objects variable name will not update the reference.

Comment: Agreed. If you are saving multiple objects to the DB in one go, might I suggest rewriting this inside a transaction? (if your engine supports it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP stores the reference of the variable to use it. When you call `$qry->bindParam(1, $obj->qux, PDO::PARAM_INT)`, the reference stored is the reference of the member of the instanciated class.

When you change the member `$obj->qux`, the reference is still the same than the one stored in  your `$obj`. However, if you reinstanciate `$obj` to a new class, then every references are changed, but your old object is still in memory ! So when you assign a new value to the new `$obj->qux`, it is not the same variable used, so running `$qry->execute` will use the old value.

I hope I've been clear enough.